# Trying to understand Tomcat 7 SSL Ciphers

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

I am trying to figure out exactly how ciphers work in Tomcat 7. From what I gather, I don't think order matters in your server.xml file for the HTTPS connector. As in, if you order the cipher in a particular order, it checks in that order, it just needs to match any. Would this be correct?

Also, I tried removing all ciphers and just left it as ciphers = "" in my file but it still worked when I reloaded tomcat. As in, I got a secure connection to the host with AES_128_CBC with SHA1 and DHE_RSA. Any reason why this would happen? Would there happen to be another place that has available ciphers listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The order ciphers are listed does not determine the order they are selected.
2. I suspect if you specify a blank value that the default ciphers are used.